RefreshIndicator not working when data count is one in Flutter
I’m using RefreshIndicator to implement pull-to-refresh functionality in my Flutter app. It works perfectly when there are multiple items in the list. However, when the list contains only one item, the refresh indicator does not appear.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> items = ["Item 1"];

  Future<void> _refresh() async {
    // Simulate network request
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {
      items.add("New Item");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("RefreshIndicator Example")),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _refresh,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(items[index]));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How can I ensure that the RefreshIndicator works even when there is only one item in the list? Is there a specific configuration or workaround needed for this scenario?

This is caused by scroll view not having enough area to scroll. You can make sure to trigger the refresh method by making the scroll view always scrollable:
physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

